# Disable or Remove Inspect element function from right click menu with Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to disable or remove only Inspect element function from right click menu with help of Javascript or jQuery

I know you can completely disable right click with **e.preventDefault());**

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => e.preventDefault());
```

And i want Right Click menu works with all options except inspect element, it **disable only inspect element function** in right click menu.

like it find the word `*inspect*` in menu option and disable that option which contain word `*inspect*`

**Added more details to my question:**
...or is that possible if i completely disable the right click menu with **`e.preventDefault();`**  and only allow open images in new tab with right click without other options in the menu?  i mean with right click it only show open image in new tab.

is that any solution for this in Javascript or jQuery

Comment: Why though? Wouldn't stop me from viewing the source or downloading it. I can't see how disabling 'inspect element' would accomplish anything.

Comment: it is barely possible since it is browser's feature.

Comment: curveball yea it is browser feature but as you said the word 'barely' instead of impossible. so that makes me courage to ask this question :) , and if it works then you can also disable other menu options too

Comment: [Is it possible to remove "Inspect Element"?](/questions/28690564)

Comment: padaleiana, I know you can prevent this option with by disable the keyboard shortcut keys but here i am asking about how to disable specific option in right click menu of mouse right click. not keyboard

Comment: (Don't forget to put _@_ when you mention someone. Luckily I saw your comment) I know, you mentioned it multiple times. Did you see all the answers in that question?

Answer (score 0):

you can loop all menu items and block them

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  for (let i = 0; i < e.target.children.length; i++) {
    const menuItem = e.target.children[i];

    // Check "Inspect"
    if (menuItem.textContent.toLowerCase().includes('inspect')) {
      // Prevent the default action for this specific item
      menuItem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: it won't works, it totally disable the right click menu. i tried on firefox chrome, do you give a example on jsfiddle.

Comment: I looked into it more, and unfortunately, you cannot choose to turn off or remove just the "Inspect" option. sorry!!!